# не могу понять что делать с return

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

есть задания на сололерн для новичков на пайтоне, перед сертификатом (типа дипломный проект)

смысл задания проверить есть ли в вводимом предложении слово, если да то вывести одно, если нет, другое, смысл в том что бы функция возвращала только либо "да, есть это слово", "нет, нет этого слова"
получается функция работает, и выдает решение

но помимо этого еще сверху выходит ретурн, который я не могу нормально перенаправить(пытался делать ретурн принта, очевидно не работает, так как первый ретурн гасит следующий) или как то устранить, и из за этого все тесты ложатся, так как ожидают вывод только либо да либо нет, без вывода слова, если удалить ретурн получается None
помогите пожалуйста

```
text = input()
word = input()

def search(text, word):
    if text.count(word):
        True 
        print("Word found")
    else:
        print("Word not found")
    return word # здесь я поставил так, что бы вернуть слово, если убрать ретурн он вернет None
print(search(text, word))
```

Answer (score 2):

что мешает делать так:

```
def search(text, word):
    if text.count(word):
        print("Word found")
        return word
    else:
        print("Word not found")
```

А в вашем примере вообще надо так (насколько я понял задачу и ваш пример):

```
text = input()
word = input()

def search(text, word):
    if text.count(word):
        return "Word found"
    else:
        return "Word not found"

print(search(text, word))
```

или функцию можно записать в 1 строчку

```
def search(text, word):
    return "Word found" if text.count(word) else "Word not found"
```